# How to make object change in contact

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have a object in the scene which is determine by:

```
SKSpriteNode* object = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:_objectTexture];
[object setScale:2];
object.position = CGPointMake(0, y);
object.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:object.size];
object.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
```

then if my character hit it, it will stay there. Now, I want whenever the character hit the object, the object also move its upper half. How it moves depends on the index.

```
if index value in range 1, object change texture
if index value in range 2, object and character reflex by normal physical contact law
if index value in range 3, object broken into half
```

I tried to put

```
object.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
```

then I saw it pulled down and disappear by gravity.
How do I set object dynamic and condition to satisfy the above need?
Thanks a lot for your help !

Added (as requested): My delegate method:

```
@interface MyScene () <SKPhysicsContactDelegate> {
SKSpriteNode* _character;
SKTexture* _object1;
SKTexture* _object2;
SKAction* _moveObjects;
SKNode* _moving;
SKNode* _objects;
BOOL _canRestart;
NSInteger _index;
SKTexture* characterTexture;

SKSpriteNode* _characterSprite;
```

}

later part (not sure if it is relevant)

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size{


if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    /*Setup Scene here */


    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, -6.0);
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
```

My objects are moved on scence by:

```
CGFloat distanceToMove = self.frame.size.width + 2 * _object1.size.width;
    SKAction* moveObjects = [SKAction moveByX:-distanceToMove y:0 duration:0.01* distanceToMove];
    SKAction* removeObjects = [SKAction removeFromParent];
    _moveObjectsAndRemove = [SKAction sequence:@[moveObjects,removeObjects]];
```

Ps: add didBeginContact:

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact{
if (_moving.speed > 0) {

    //Score node
    if ((contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask & scoreCategory) == scoreCategory || (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask & scoreCategory) == scoreCategory)
    {
        _score++;

        // Add a little visual
        [_scoreLabelNode runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction scaleTo:1.5 duration:0.1], [SKAction scaleTo:1.0 duration:0.1]]]];
    }

    else
    //Collided with world
    {            
    _moving.speed = 0;
    _character.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = worldCategory;
    [_character runAction:[SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI * _character.position.y*0.01 duration:_character.position.y * 0.03] completion:^{_character.speed = 0; }];
     ....   
 }

}
```

Comment: post the -didbegincontact method

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

```
object.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
```

Comment: Yes. That help to avoid pulling down effect, thanks! But now the objects move like a mess in my scene, even when it is not hit by character. I want it stay at the same position and only move some parts.

Comment: Please post your contact delegate methods

Comment: The objects also being moved on the scene. But before it get contact to character I already see it moved like a mess.

Comment: Well, if you are using multiple parts, it would be best to implement them separately as SKSpriteNodes

Comment: Do you mean separate the object to multiple parts ? It sounds quite complicated without an example ...

Comment: What is your current implementation?

Comment: I implement a game. There is contact simulation in the game, where character can collide with object in the scene. if you want we can move to chat.